# In what way should I ask a question?

Tags: word-order, questions, auxiliary-verbs

What is the right way to ask a question in terms of its word order?

**first:**

> What the impact it **has**?
>
> What the name it **has**?
>
> What the taste the water **had**?
>
> What **was** the taste of the water?

**second:**

> What the impact **does it have**?
>
> What the name it **does it have**?
>
> What the taste the water **did have**?
>
> What the taste of the water **was**?

Comment: The answer to this other question might be helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/84529/

Comment: "What impact does it have?" and usually we say "How did the water taste?" or "What did the water taste like?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first set you showed is correct only for the "What **was** the taste of the water?"

The second set has the first three nearly correct. 
What impact **does it have**?

What name **does it have**?

What taste **did** the water **have**?

You don't need to include an article in front of "name", "impact", or "taste".